# What is the episode where person is the power source for the city defense shield?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

In the episode a city is being attacked by the bad guys. The defense shield for the city doesn't work because part of it was stolen by the black ops technology thieves from earth. What is the episode?

Thanks to everyone! You helped me find this quote:

> My people have depended on the sentinel for 300 years. It is created
>   to be there always. So that we may feel free to pursue matters of the
>   mind and spirit without fear of what is happening now.

Comment: I don't see an actual question.

Comment: Thanks guys! I was looking for this quote (posted in the question)

Comment: @onewho - perhaps bad guys stole it ;-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe the episode you are looking for is [Stargate SG-1, Season 5: Episode 20, "The Sentinel"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0709165/)

Answer (score 10):

There is a pattern here that appears in several other episodes of SG1; In addition to [The Sentinel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sentinel_%28Stargate_SG-1%29#ep108) (the answer), [Touchstone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touchstone_%28Stargate_SG-1%29#ep36) **and** [Thor's Chariot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thor%27s_Chariot#ep28) each feature a device that is protecting the inhabitants of the planet, then someone from Earth comes along and alters/removes/destroys it, and then SG1 has to come in and save the day.

Comment: This is probably more appropriate as a comment than an Answer, since it doesn't address the op's Question at all, but comments on the episode's morals.

Comment: @Mufasa The Sentinel is the **answer**, the rest doesn't comment on the morals but on the plot...which I thought was interesting enough to include.

Comment: There's also [Dome City](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Beneath_the_Surface), where a dome (maintained by slaves) keeps the surface-dwellers alive.